# LinkedIn API request fails with "Resource reactions does not exist"

Tags: linkedin-api

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 0,
    "message": "Resource reactions does not exist",
    "status": 404
}
```

Getting above error when trying to retrieve reactions on share. Following this request according to documentation.

`GET "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/reactions/(entity:{entityUrn})?q=entity&sort={sortOrder}"`

My request

```
GET 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/reactions/urn:li:share:6655188984098103296?q=share&sort=desc&oauth2_access_token=<access-token>'
```

What am i doing wrong here? Post share has reaction to it. I'm unable to understand what they mean by entity and q. I've tried all forms of sort order like abbreviations also. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the entityUrn. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/protocol-version

You also need to set the `X-Restli-Protocol-Version` to `2.0.0`

So your request might look like:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/reactions/(entity:urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A1234567)?q=entity`

Comment: I would just like to point out to anyone else that arrives here from google that the api url is case-sensitive as well. In my case, I was getting a similar error from going to `/v2/userInfo` instead of `/v2/userinfo`